# Datefromparts and datepart puzzle

Tags: sql, sql-server, datepart

Can someone tell what I'm doing wrong in SQL Server to fail to make the below on today (which is 2023-03-16) not read 3-20-2023?

Basically I need to return today's date only the day always has to be 20.

```
DECLARE @year int = CONVERT(int,datepart(yyyy, GETDATE()))
DECLARE @month int = CONVERT(int,datepart(m, GETDATE()))
DECLARE @day int = 20

SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(@month, @day, @year)
```

Comment: The conversions are unnecessary, that's for be sure. The arguments to `datefromparts` are in the wrong order though.

Comment: Doesn't make sense - if the DAY is always 20 then the only time that will be valid is on the 20th of each month.  It can never be the 16th (today).  What are you really trying to do with this?

Comment: @Jeff - they are trying to  get the date that the 20th day of the current month/year is. (which they would get if they put the `DATEFROMPARTS` arguments in the right order!) - their self answer confirms this is what they are attempting

Comment: @MartinSmith - if that is what they are asking for.  The OP says they need to return today's date only the day is always 20.  That is not the same as asking for the 20th of the current month.

Answer (score 0):

this works:

> ```
> declare @month varchar(2) = month(getdate())
> declare @year varchar(4) = year(getdate())
> declare @day varchar(2) = '20' select @year + '-' + @month  + '-' + @day
> ```

Comment: But will fail over 77 year.... , why not put the arguments to `DATEFROMPARTS()` in the right order ?  (see: [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16))

Comment: If SQL is still used in 77 years, i hope OP will get a refund

Answer (score 0):

DATEFROMPARTS needs to be in year,moth,day format to work. Once you fix that you
can convert it to any style you need.

```
 DECLARE @year int = CONVERT(int,datepart(yyyy, getdate()))
 DECLARE @month int = CONVERT(int,datepart(m, getdate()))
 DECLARE @day int = 20

     SELECT CONVERT(varchar, (datefromparts(@year, @month, @day )),10)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Basically I need to return today's date only the day always has to be
> 20.

You can use the below for this (get last day of previous month and add 20 days to it)

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,20,EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1))
```

Or if you are on SQL Server 2022 you may prefer

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,19,DATETRUNC ( MONTH , GETDATE()))
```